# Proper way to receive clicked item from GridView

Tags: android, gridview, parameters, android-activity

What are the best practices of getting item from clicked cell in `GridView`?

Assume that `GridView` items (cells) are filled using `BaseAdapter`. And item contains of picture and text. How would you pass that unique clicked item to another activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set listener:

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and override this method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
   ... start your activity here ... (i stands for your clicked element)
}
```